# JavaScript. Web browser Error: "ReferenceError: Function is not defined"

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

JavaScript. Web browser Error: "ReferenceError: Function is not defined".
I always call this JavaScript file. It never works. The error "ReferenceError: CMenu is not defined" always appears in the web browser's debugger. Why? How can I solve it? I call the javascript when I start loading in the web browser of a Splunk dashboard.
The script calls the function on line 680. I do not know why the error. The function is defined higher up in the same JavaScript file. Thank you very much. I need help.

```js
//circular-menu

(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.CMenu = factory());
}(this, function () { 'use strict';

    function rotateDeg (i){
        return this.startDeg + this.rotateUnit * i;
    }

    function rotateDeg$1 (i){
        return - (this.rotateDeg(i) + this.unskewDeg);
    }

    function startDeg(config) {
        var top = -(config.totalAngle - 180) / 2,
            positions = {
                top: top,
    top1: top + 40,
    top2: top + 80,    
    top3: top + 120, 
    top4: top + 160, 
    top5: top + 200, 
    top6: top + 240, 
    top7: top + 280, 
    top8: top + 320, 
                left: top - 90,
                right: top + 90,
                bottom: top + 180
            };

        return config.start !== undefined ? config.start : positions[config.position];
    }

    const antialiasing = 3;

    function coverRadius(radius, percent) {
        var square = radius * radius * 2;
        return Math.sqrt(square) * percent + antialiasing;
    }

    function coverSize (coverRadius) {
        var l = coverRadius * 2;
        var m = -l / 2;

        l += "px";
        m += "px";
        
        return {
            width:  l,
            height: l,
            marginLeft: m,
            marginTop: m
        };
    }

    function menuSize (config) {
        var l = config.diameter;
        var m = - config.diameter / 2;

        l += "px";
        m += "px";

        return {
            width:  l,
            height: l,
            marginLeft: m,
            marginTop: m
        };
    }

    const fixedTop  = 10;

    function clickZoneSize (config) {
        var l = config.diameter;
        var m = - config.diameter / 2;

        l += "px";
        m += "px";

        return {
            width:  l,
            height: l,
            marginRight: m,
            marginBottom: m
        };
    }

    function listSize (config) {
        var l = (config.diameter / 2) + 'px';

        return {
            width:  l,
            height: l
        };
    }

    const middleRatio = 0.41;

    function textTop (clickZoneRadius) {
        return clickZoneRadius * middleRatio - fixedTop + 'px';

    }

    function Calculation(config) {
        this._config = config;

        var c = this.config = config,
            itemsNum = c.menus.length,
            spaceNumber = c.totalAngle === 360 ? itemsNum : itemsNum - 1;

        this.radius = config.diameter / 2;
        this.coverRadius = coverRadius(this.radius, config.percent);
        this.clickZoneRadius = this.radius - this.coverRadius;



        this.listSize = listSize(config);
        this.clickZoneSize = clickZoneSize(config);
        this.menuSize = menuSize(config);
        this.coverSize = coverSize(this.coverRadius);
        this.startDeg = startDeg(config);
        this.centralDeg = (c.totalAngle - (c.spaceDeg * spaceNumber)) / itemsNum;
        this.rotateUnit = this.centralDeg + c.spaceDeg;
        this.skewDeg = 90 - this.centralDeg;
        this.unskewDeg = - (90 - this.centralDeg / 2);
        this.textTop = textTop(this.clickZoneRadius);
    }

    Calculation.prototype = {
        constructor: Calculation,
        rotateDeg: rotateDeg,
        horizontalDeg: rotateDeg$1
    };

    function createLists (parent) {
        
        this._config.menus.forEach(function(v, k){

            this._createList(parent, v, k);
            
        }, this);

    }

    function defaultView(node) {
        return (node.ownerDocument && node.ownerDocument.defaultView) // node is a Node
            || (node.document && node) // node is a Window
            || node.defaultView; // node is a Document
    }

    function styleRemove(name) {
        this.style.removeProperty(name);
    }

    function styleConstant(name, value, priority) {
        this.style.setProperty(name, value, priority);
    }

    function styleFunction(name, value, priority) {
        var v = value.apply(this, arguments);
        if (v == null) this.style.removeProperty(name);
        else this.style.setProperty(name, v, priority);
    }

    function style(ele, name, value, priority) {

        var node;
        return arguments.length > 1
            ? ((value == null
            ? styleRemove : typeof value === "function"
            ? styleFunction
            : styleConstant).call(ele, name, value, priority == null ? "" : priority))
            : defaultView(node = ele)
            .getComputedStyle(node, null)
            .getPropertyValue(name);
    }

    function createList(parent, data, index){

        var list = document.createElement('li');
        style(list, 'width', this._calc.listSize.width);
        style(list, 'height', this._calc.listSize.height);
        style(list, 'transform', 'rotate('+ this._calc.rotateDeg(index) +'deg) skew('+ this._calc.skewDeg +'deg)');

        parent.appendChild(list);

        this._createAnchor(list, data, index);

    }

    function classArray(string) {
        return string.trim().split(/^|\s+/);
    }

    function classList(node) {
        return node.classList || new ClassList(node);
    }

    function ClassList(node) {
        this._node = node;
        this._names = classArray(node.getAttribute("class") || "");
    }

    ClassList.prototype = {
        add: function(name) {
            var i = this._names.indexOf(name);
            if (i < 0) {
                this._names.push(name);
                this._node.setAttribute("class", this._names.join(" "));
            }
        },
        remove: function(name) {
            var i = this._names.indexOf(name);
            if (i >= 0) {
                this._names.splice(i, 1);
                this._node.setAttribute("class", this._names.join(" "));
            }
        },
        contains: function(name) {
            return this._names.indexOf(name) >= 0;
        }
    };

    function classedAdd(node, names) {
        var list = classList(node), i = -1, n = names.length;
        while (++i < n) list.add(names[i]);
    }

    function classedRemove(node, names) {
        var list = classList(node), i = -1, n = names.length;
        while (++i < n) list.remove(names[i]);
    }

    function classedTrue(names) {
        classedAdd(this, names);
    }

    function classedFalse(names) {
        classedRemove(this, names);
    }

    function classedFunction(names, value) {
        (value.apply(this, arguments) ? classedAdd : classedRemove)(this, names);
    }

    function classed(ele, name, value) {
        var names = classArray(name + "");

        if (arguments.length < 2) {
            var list = classList(this), i = -1, n = names.length;
            while (++i < n) if (!list.contains(names[i])) return false;
            return true;
        }

        var callee = (typeof value === "function"
            ? classedFunction : value
            ? classedTrue
            : classedFalse).call(ele, names, value);
    }

    var UID = {
        _current: 0,
        getNew: function(){
            this._current++;
            return this._current;
        }
    };
    function styleSheet (element, prop, value, pseudo) {
        
        var _this = element;
        var _sheetId = "sheetStyles";
        var _head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var _sheet = document.getElementById(_sheetId) || document.createElement('style');
        _sheet.id = _sheetId;
        var className = "s-S" + UID.getNew();
        
        _this.className += " " + className;



        _sheet.innerHTML += " ." + className + ( pseudo ? (":" + pseudo) : "" ) + "{" + prop + ":" + value + "}";
        _head.appendChild(_sheet);
        return this;
    };

    function on (ele, type, callback, data) {
        ele.addEventListener(type, function(e){
            callback.call(this, e, data);
        });
    }

    function createMenu(){
        var p = this._container;

        classed(p, 'circular-menu', true);
        style(p, 'width', this._calc.menuSize.width);
        style(p, 'height', this._calc.menuSize.height);
        style(p, 'margin-top', this._calc.menuSize.marginTop);
        style(p, 'margin-left', this._calc.menuSize.marginLeft);
        
        var self = this;
        on(p, "click", function(e){
            if(e.toElement === p){
                self._cMenu.hide();
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            style(p, 'display', 'block');
        },100);

        styleSheet(p, 'width', this._calc.coverSize.width, 'after');
        styleSheet(p, 'height', this._calc.coverSize.height, 'after');
        styleSheet(p, 'margin-left', this._calc.coverSize.marginLeft, 'after');
        styleSheet(p, 'margin-top', this._calc.coverSize.marginTop, 'after');
        styleSheet(p, 'border', "3px solid " + this._config.pageBackground, 'after');


        var ul = p.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
        this._createLists(ul);
    }

    function hasSubMenus(menus) {
        return menus instanceof Array && menus.length !== 0;
    }
    function ifDisabled(disabled){
        if(disabled instanceof Function)
            return disabled();
        else
            return Boolean(disabled);
    }

    function setHref(ele, href){
        if(!href) return;

        if(href instanceof Object){
            ele.href = href.url;
            ele.target = href.blank? "_blank" : "";
        }else{
            ele.href = href;
        }
    }



    var delayShow = null;// delayShow reference the last setTimeout triggered by any one of menu item(anchor)

    function createAnchor (parent, data, index) {
        var self = this;

        var delayHide = null;// delayHide reference the last setTimeout triggered by the menu item itself

        var a = document.createElement('a');

        setHref(a, data.href);

        a.setDisabled = function(){
            classed(a, 'disabled', ifDisabled(data.disabled));
        };
        this._anchors.push(a);


        style(a, 'width', this._calc.clickZoneSize.width);
        style(a, 'height', this._calc.clickZoneSize.height);
        style(a, 'right', this._calc.clickZoneSize.marginRight);
        style(a, 'bottom', this._calc.clickZoneSize.marginBottom);
        style(a, 'transform', 'skew(' + -this._calc.skewDeg + 'deg) rotate(' + this._calc.unskewDeg + 'deg) scale(1)');

        classed(a, 'disabled', ifDisabled(data.disabled));


        var percent = this._config.percent * 100 + "%";
        styleSheet(a, 'background', 'radial-gradient(transparent ' + percent + ', ' + this._config.background + ' ' + percent + ')');
        styleSheet(a, 'background', 'radial-gradient(transparent ' + percent + ', ' + this._config.backgroundHover + ' ' + percent + ')', 'hover');


        function clickCallBack(e, data){
            if (data.click) data.click.call(this, e, data);

            if(self._config.hideAfterClick){
                self._cMenu.hide();
                if(self._cMenu._pMenu) self._cMenu._pMenu.hide();
                if(subMenu) subMenu.hide();
            }
        }

        on(a, 'click', clickCallBack, data);

        parent.appendChild(a);

        this._createHorizontal(a, data, index);
        
        
        //toggle subMenu
        if (hasSubMenus(data.menus)) {
            var subMenu = this._createSubMenu(self, data.menus, index);

            on(a, 'mouseenter', function () {

                delayShow = setTimeout(function () {
                    subMenu
                        .styles({
                                    top: self._container.offsetTop + self._calc.radius + 'px',
                                    left: self._container.offsetLeft + self._calc.radius + 'px'
                                })
                        .show();
                }, 150);
            });

            on(a, 'mouseleave', function (e) {
                if (!subMenu._container.contains(e.toElement)) {
                    delayHide = setTimeout(function () {
                        subMenu.hide();
                    }, 200);
                }
            });

            on(subMenu._container, 'mouseenter', function () {
                clearTimeout(delayShow);
                clearTimeout(delayHide);
            });

            on(subMenu._container, 'mouseleave', function (e) {
                if (!a.contains(e.toElement) || e.toElement.children[0] === a) {
                    subMenu.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    const sizeRatio = 0.65;
    const marginTopRatio = 0.2;
    const fontHeight = 13;

    function hasIcon(icon){
        if(icon === undefined) return false;
        else if(typeof icon === "string") return icon !== "";
        else return icon.length && icon[0] !== "";
    }

    function getIcon(icon){
        return typeof icon === "string"? icon : icon[0];
    }

    function getIconColor(icon){
        return typeof icon === "string"? null : icon[1];
    }

    function createIcon (parent, data, index) {
        if(!hasIcon(data.icon)) return;

        var span = document.createElement('span');

        var icon = getIcon(data.icon),
            color = getIconColor(data.icon);

        classed(span, icon + " cm-icon", true);
        style(span, 'color', color);

        var l = this._calc.clickZoneRadius * sizeRatio - fontHeight + "px",
            m = this._calc.clickZoneRadius * marginTopRatio - fontHeight + "px";
        style(span, 'width', l);
        style(span, 'height', l);
        style(span, 'font-size', l);
        style(span, 'margin-top', m);

        parent.appendChild(span);
    }

    const withIconMarginTop = "3px";
    const withIconTop = "-3px";

    function createText (parent, data, index) {

        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = data.title;

        classed(span, 'text', true);
        style(span, 'margin-top', hasIcon(data.icon)? withIconMarginTop : this._calc.textTop);
        style(span, 'top', hasIcon(data.icon)? withIconTop : 0);

        parent.appendChild(span);
    }

    function createHorizontal (parent, data, index) {

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        classed(div, "horizontal", true);

        if(this._config.horizontal) style(div, 'transform', 'rotate('+ this._calc.horizontalDeg(index) +'deg)');

        parent.appendChild(div);

        this._createIcon(div, data, index);
        this._createText(div, data, index);
    }

    function extend$1 () {
        // Variables
        var extended = {};
        var deep = false;
        var i = 0;
        var length = arguments.length;

        // Check if a deep merge
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) === '[object Boolean]') {
            deep = arguments[0];
            i++;
        }

        // Merge the object into the extended object
        var merge = function (obj) {
            for (var prop in obj) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
                    // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
                    if (deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]') {
                        extended[prop] = extend(true, extended[prop], obj[prop]);
                    } else {
                        extended[prop] = obj[prop];
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            var obj = arguments[i];
            merge(obj);
        }

        return extended;

    };

    const sizeRatio$1 = 5 / 3;
    const percentRatio = 0.45;
    const centralDegRatio = 0.618;


    function createSubMenu(creator, menus, index) {
        var subMenu = document.createElement('div');

        classed(subMenu, 'circular-sub-menu', true);

        this._container.parentNode.insertBefore(subMenu, this._container);

        var totalAngle = this._calc.centralDeg * centralDegRatio * menus.length;
        var startDeg = this._calc.rotateDeg(index) - totalAngle / 2 + this._calc.centralDeg / 2;

        var config = extend$1(this._config, {
            totalAngle: totalAngle,//deg,
            percent: percentRatio,//%
            diameter: this._config.diameter * sizeRatio$1,//px
            start: startDeg,//deg
            animation: "into",
            menus: menus
        });
        
        return new CMenu(subMenu, creator._cMenu)
            .config(config);
    }

    function Creator(cMenu, config){
        this._cMenu = cMenu;
        this._container = cMenu._container;
        this._config = config;
        this._calc = new Calculation(config);
        this._anchors = [];
    }


    Creator.prototype = {
        constructor: Creator,
        createMenu: createMenu,
        _createLists: createLists,
        _createList: createList,
        _createAnchor: createAnchor,
        _createText: createText,
        _createHorizontal: createHorizontal,
        _createIcon: createIcon,
        _createSubMenu: createSubMenu
    };

    const defaultConfig = {
        totalAngle: 360,//deg,
        spaceDeg: 0,//deg
        background: "#323232",
        backgroundHover: "#515151",
        pageBackground: "transparent",
        percent: 0.32,//%
        diameter: 300,//px
        position: 'top',
        horizontal: true,
        animation: "into",
        hideAfterClick: true
    };


    function config (config) {

        config = extend$1(defaultConfig, config);

        this._creator = new Creator(this, config);
        this._creator.createMenu();

        return this;
    }

    function setCoordinate(coordinate){
        if( !(coordinate instanceof Array) || !(coordinate.length === 2) ) return;

        //TODO verify if has unit
        style(this._container, 'left', coordinate[0] + "px");
        style(this._container, 'top', coordinate[1] + "px");
    }

    //check disabled

    function setDisabled(){
        this._creator._anchors.forEach(function(v){
            v.setDisabled();
        });
    }

    function show (coordinate) {


        setDisabled.call(this);

        setCoordinate.call(this, coordinate);

        classed(this._container, 'opened-nav', true);
        return this;
    }

    function hide () {
        classed(this._container, 'opened-nav', false);
        return this;
    }

    function styles (styles) {
        if(!styles instanceof Object) return this;
        
        for(var k in styles){
            if(styles.hasOwnProperty(k)) style(this._container, k, styles[k]);
        }

        return this;
    }

    function CMenu(element, pMenu){
        this._container = element;
        
        if(pMenu) this._pMenu = pMenu;
    }

    CMenu.prototype = {
        constructor: CMenu,
        config: config,
        show: show,
        hide: hide,
        styles: styles

    };

    function index (selector) {
        return typeof selector === "string"
            ? new CMenu(document.querySelector(selector))
            : new CMenu(selector);
    }

    return index;

}));

//circular-menu

    var cmenu = CMenu("#circle-menu1")
     var cmenu = CMenu(ele)
            .config({
                        totalAngle: 40,//deg,
                        spaceDeg: 0,//deg
                        background: "#52BCEC",
                        backgroundHover: "#d3d3d3",
                        percent: 0.20,//%
                        diameter: 270,//px
                        position: 'top1',
                        horizontal: true,
      hideAfterClick: false,
                        animation: "into",
                        menus: [
       {
                                title: 'Global Finance',
                                icon: '',
                                href: '#5',
                                menus: [
                                    {
                                        title: 'DELTA - CLAN',
                                        icon: '',
          menus: [
           {
            title: 'ANS CLAN',
            icon: '',
           }
          ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                        ]
                    }).show();
```

Comment: Is there any module loader active on that page?

Comment: [Code samples](/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. The posted sample has too much extraneous code. Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article, and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Answer (score 0):

a few things you can check in these 'can't find it' cases:

1. scopes - functions and object are created in scopes, possibly with different timings, which means you have to verify that 'function CMenu()..' already exist when you call it. just a quick look in your code thought me that you call CMenu outside of the scope in which it was created, which may lead to the problem.
   a scope can be any code block surrounded by braces, e.g. {..code..}
2. var and let - let disappears when the function ends, and var stays. not really relevant here, but just in case someone else stumbles here for a different reason.
3. should be the first option, check casing. js var names are case sensitive.

Hope that helps, 
eiran

Answer (score 0):

The code that I am using is this. The code that I added before was just a previous test.
This code does not work, on line 681 Why does not it recognize the CMenu function? The CMenu function is defined above in the same file but in the web browser the error always appears saying that the function is not defined.
Thank you very much.

```js
//circular-menu

(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.CMenu = factory());
}(this, function () { 'use strict';

    function rotateDeg (i){
        return this.startDeg + this.rotateUnit * i;
    }

    function rotateDeg$1 (i){
        return - (this.rotateDeg(i) + this.unskewDeg);
    }

    function startDeg(config) {
        var top = -(config.totalAngle - 180) / 2,
            positions = {
                top: top,
    top1: top + 40,
    top2: top + 80,    
    top3: top + 120, 
    top4: top + 160, 
    top5: top + 200, 
    top6: top + 240, 
    top7: top + 280, 
    top8: top + 320, 
                left: top - 90,
                right: top + 90,
                bottom: top + 180
            };

        return config.start !== undefined ? config.start : positions[config.position];
    }

    const antialiasing = 3;

    function coverRadius(radius, percent) {
        var square = radius * radius * 2;
        return Math.sqrt(square) * percent + antialiasing;
    }

    function coverSize (coverRadius) {
        var l = coverRadius * 2;
        var m = -l / 2;

        l += "px";
        m += "px";
        
        return {
            width:  l,
            height: l,
            marginLeft: m,
            marginTop: m
        };
    }

    function menuSize (config) {
        var l = config.diameter;
        var m = - config.diameter / 2;

        l += "px";
        m += "px";

        return {
            width:  l,
            height: l,
            marginLeft: m,
            marginTop: m
        };
    }

    const fixedTop  = 10;

    function clickZoneSize (config) {
        var l = config.diameter;
        var m = - config.diameter / 2;

        l += "px";
        m += "px";

        return {
            width:  l,
            height: l,
            marginRight: m,
            marginBottom: m
        };
    }

    function listSize (config) {
        var l = (config.diameter / 2) + 'px';

        return {
            width:  l,
            height: l
        };
    }

    const middleRatio = 0.41;

    function textTop (clickZoneRadius) {
        return clickZoneRadius * middleRatio - fixedTop + 'px';

    }

    function Calculation(config) {
        this._config = config;

        var c = this.config = config,
            itemsNum = c.menus.length,
            spaceNumber = c.totalAngle === 360 ? itemsNum : itemsNum - 1;

        this.radius = config.diameter / 2;
        this.coverRadius = coverRadius(this.radius, config.percent);
        this.clickZoneRadius = this.radius - this.coverRadius;



        this.listSize = listSize(config);
        this.clickZoneSize = clickZoneSize(config);
        this.menuSize = menuSize(config);
        this.coverSize = coverSize(this.coverRadius);
        this.startDeg = startDeg(config);
        this.centralDeg = (c.totalAngle - (c.spaceDeg * spaceNumber)) / itemsNum;
        this.rotateUnit = this.centralDeg + c.spaceDeg;
        this.skewDeg = 90 - this.centralDeg;
        this.unskewDeg = - (90 - this.centralDeg / 2);
        this.textTop = textTop(this.clickZoneRadius);
    }

    Calculation.prototype = {
        constructor: Calculation,
        rotateDeg: rotateDeg,
        horizontalDeg: rotateDeg$1
    };

    function createLists (parent) {
        
        this._config.menus.forEach(function(v, k){

            this._createList(parent, v, k);
            
        }, this);

    }

    function defaultView(node) {
        return (node.ownerDocument && node.ownerDocument.defaultView) // node is a Node
            || (node.document && node) // node is a Window
            || node.defaultView; // node is a Document
    }

    function styleRemove(name) {
        this.style.removeProperty(name);
    }

    function styleConstant(name, value, priority) {
        this.style.setProperty(name, value, priority);
    }

    function styleFunction(name, value, priority) {
        var v = value.apply(this, arguments);
        if (v == null) this.style.removeProperty(name);
        else this.style.setProperty(name, v, priority);
    }

    function style(ele, name, value, priority) {

        var node;
        return arguments.length > 1
            ? ((value == null
            ? styleRemove : typeof value === "function"
            ? styleFunction
            : styleConstant).call(ele, name, value, priority == null ? "" : priority))
            : defaultView(node = ele)
            .getComputedStyle(node, null)
            .getPropertyValue(name);
    }

    function createList(parent, data, index){

        var list = document.createElement('li');
        style(list, 'width', this._calc.listSize.width);
        style(list, 'height', this._calc.listSize.height);
        style(list, 'transform', 'rotate('+ this._calc.rotateDeg(index) +'deg) skew('+ this._calc.skewDeg +'deg)');

        parent.appendChild(list);

        this._createAnchor(list, data, index);

    }

    function classArray(string) {
        return string.trim().split(/^|\s+/);
    }

    function classList(node) {
        return node.classList || new ClassList(node);
    }

    function ClassList(node) {
        this._node = node;
        this._names = classArray(node.getAttribute("class") || "");
    }

    ClassList.prototype = {
        add: function(name) {
            var i = this._names.indexOf(name);
            if (i < 0) {
                this._names.push(name);
                this._node.setAttribute("class", this._names.join(" "));
            }
        },
        remove: function(name) {
            var i = this._names.indexOf(name);
            if (i >= 0) {
                this._names.splice(i, 1);
                this._node.setAttribute("class", this._names.join(" "));
            }
        },
        contains: function(name) {
            return this._names.indexOf(name) >= 0;
        }
    };

    function classedAdd(node, names) {
        var list = classList(node), i = -1, n = names.length;
        while (++i < n) list.add(names[i]);
    }

    function classedRemove(node, names) {
        var list = classList(node), i = -1, n = names.length;
        while (++i < n) list.remove(names[i]);
    }

    function classedTrue(names) {
        classedAdd(this, names);
    }

    function classedFalse(names) {
        classedRemove(this, names);
    }

    function classedFunction(names, value) {
        (value.apply(this, arguments) ? classedAdd : classedRemove)(this, names);
    }

    function classed(ele, name, value) {
        var names = classArray(name + "");

        if (arguments.length < 2) {
            var list = classList(this), i = -1, n = names.length;
            while (++i < n) if (!list.contains(names[i])) return false;
            return true;
        }

        var callee = (typeof value === "function"
            ? classedFunction : value
            ? classedTrue
            : classedFalse).call(ele, names, value);
    }

    var UID = {
        _current: 0,
        getNew: function(){
            this._current++;
            return this._current;
        }
    };
    function styleSheet (element, prop, value, pseudo) {
        
        var _this = element;
        var _sheetId = "sheetStyles";
        var _head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var _sheet = document.getElementById(_sheetId) || document.createElement('style');
        _sheet.id = _sheetId;
        var className = "s-S" + UID.getNew();
        
        _this.className += " " + className;



        _sheet.innerHTML += " ." + className + ( pseudo ? (":" + pseudo) : "" ) + "{" + prop + ":" + value + "}";
        _head.appendChild(_sheet);
        return this;
    };

    function on (ele, type, callback, data) {
        ele.addEventListener(type, function(e){
            callback.call(this, e, data);
        });
    }

    function createMenu(){
        var p = this._container;

        classed(p, 'circular-menu', true);
        style(p, 'width', this._calc.menuSize.width);
        style(p, 'height', this._calc.menuSize.height);
        style(p, 'margin-top', this._calc.menuSize.marginTop);
        style(p, 'margin-left', this._calc.menuSize.marginLeft);
        
        var self = this;
        on(p, "click", function(e){
            if(e.toElement === p){
                self._cMenu.hide();
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            style(p, 'display', 'block');
        },100);

        styleSheet(p, 'width', this._calc.coverSize.width, 'after');
        styleSheet(p, 'height', this._calc.coverSize.height, 'after');
        styleSheet(p, 'margin-left', this._calc.coverSize.marginLeft, 'after');
        styleSheet(p, 'margin-top', this._calc.coverSize.marginTop, 'after');
        styleSheet(p, 'border', "3px solid " + this._config.pageBackground, 'after');


        var ul = p.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
        this._createLists(ul);
    }

    function hasSubMenus(menus) {
        return menus instanceof Array && menus.length !== 0;
    }
    function ifDisabled(disabled){
        if(disabled instanceof Function)
            return disabled();
        else
            return Boolean(disabled);
    }

    function setHref(ele, href){
        if(!href) return;

        if(href instanceof Object){
            ele.href = href.url;
            ele.target = href.blank? "_blank" : "";
        }else{
            ele.href = href;
        }
    }



    var delayShow = null;// delayShow reference the last setTimeout triggered by any one of menu item(anchor)

    function createAnchor (parent, data, index) {
        var self = this;

        var delayHide = null;// delayHide reference the last setTimeout triggered by the menu item itself

        var a = document.createElement('a');

        setHref(a, data.href);

        a.setDisabled = function(){
            classed(a, 'disabled', ifDisabled(data.disabled));
        };
        this._anchors.push(a);


        style(a, 'width', this._calc.clickZoneSize.width);
        style(a, 'height', this._calc.clickZoneSize.height);
        style(a, 'right', this._calc.clickZoneSize.marginRight);
        style(a, 'bottom', this._calc.clickZoneSize.marginBottom);
        style(a, 'transform', 'skew(' + -this._calc.skewDeg + 'deg) rotate(' + this._calc.unskewDeg + 'deg) scale(1)');

        classed(a, 'disabled', ifDisabled(data.disabled));


        var percent = this._config.percent * 100 + "%";
        styleSheet(a, 'background', 'radial-gradient(transparent ' + percent + ', ' + this._config.background + ' ' + percent + ')');
        styleSheet(a, 'background', 'radial-gradient(transparent ' + percent + ', ' + this._config.backgroundHover + ' ' + percent + ')', 'hover');


        function clickCallBack(e, data){
            if (data.click) data.click.call(this, e, data);

            if(self._config.hideAfterClick){
                self._cMenu.hide();
                if(self._cMenu._pMenu) self._cMenu._pMenu.hide();
                if(subMenu) subMenu.hide();
            }
        }

        on(a, 'click', clickCallBack, data);

        parent.appendChild(a);

        this._createHorizontal(a, data, index);
        
        
        //toggle subMenu
        if (hasSubMenus(data.menus)) {
            var subMenu = this._createSubMenu(self, data.menus, index);

            on(a, 'mouseenter', function () {

                delayShow = setTimeout(function () {
                    subMenu
                        .styles({
                                    top: self._container.offsetTop + self._calc.radius + 'px',
                                    left: self._container.offsetLeft + self._calc.radius + 'px'
                                })
                        .show();
                }, 150);
            });

            on(a, 'mouseleave', function (e) {
                if (!subMenu._container.contains(e.toElement)) {
                    delayHide = setTimeout(function () {
                        subMenu.hide();
                    }, 200);
                }
            });

            on(subMenu._container, 'mouseenter', function () {
                clearTimeout(delayShow);
                clearTimeout(delayHide);
            });

            on(subMenu._container, 'mouseleave', function (e) {
                if (!a.contains(e.toElement) || e.toElement.children[0] === a) {
                    subMenu.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    const sizeRatio = 0.65;
    const marginTopRatio = 0.2;
    const fontHeight = 13;

    function hasIcon(icon){
        if(icon === undefined) return false;
        else if(typeof icon === "string") return icon !== "";
        else return icon.length && icon[0] !== "";
    }

    function getIcon(icon){
        return typeof icon === "string"? icon : icon[0];
    }

    function getIconColor(icon){
        return typeof icon === "string"? null : icon[1];
    }

    function createIcon (parent, data, index) {
        if(!hasIcon(data.icon)) return;

        var span = document.createElement('span');

        var icon = getIcon(data.icon),
            color = getIconColor(data.icon);

        classed(span, icon + " cm-icon", true);
        style(span, 'color', color);

        var l = this._calc.clickZoneRadius * sizeRatio - fontHeight + "px",
            m = this._calc.clickZoneRadius * marginTopRatio - fontHeight + "px";
        style(span, 'width', l);
        style(span, 'height', l);
        style(span, 'font-size', l);
        style(span, 'margin-top', m);

        parent.appendChild(span);
    }

    const withIconMarginTop = "3px";
    const withIconTop = "-3px";

    function createText (parent, data, index) {

        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = data.title;

        classed(span, 'text', true);
        style(span, 'margin-top', hasIcon(data.icon)? withIconMarginTop : this._calc.textTop);
        style(span, 'top', hasIcon(data.icon)? withIconTop : 0);

        parent.appendChild(span);
    }

    function createHorizontal (parent, data, index) {

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        classed(div, "horizontal", true);

        if(this._config.horizontal) style(div, 'transform', 'rotate('+ this._calc.horizontalDeg(index) +'deg)');

        parent.appendChild(div);

        this._createIcon(div, data, index);
        this._createText(div, data, index);
    }

    function extend$1 () {
        // Variables
        var extended = {};
        var deep = false;
        var i = 0;
        var length = arguments.length;

        // Check if a deep merge
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) === '[object Boolean]') {
            deep = arguments[0];
            i++;
        }

        // Merge the object into the extended object
        var merge = function (obj) {
            for (var prop in obj) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
                    // If deep merge and property is an object, merge properties
                    if (deep && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[prop]) === '[object Object]') {
                        extended[prop] = extend(true, extended[prop], obj[prop]);
                    } else {
                        extended[prop] = obj[prop];
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Loop through each object and conduct a merge
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            var obj = arguments[i];
            merge(obj);
        }

        return extended;

    };

    const sizeRatio$1 = 5 / 3;
    const percentRatio = 0.45;
    const centralDegRatio = 0.618;


    function createSubMenu(creator, menus, index) {
        var subMenu = document.createElement('div');

        classed(subMenu, 'circular-sub-menu', true);

        this._container.parentNode.insertBefore(subMenu, this._container);

        var totalAngle = this._calc.centralDeg * centralDegRatio * menus.length;
        var startDeg = this._calc.rotateDeg(index) - totalAngle / 2 + this._calc.centralDeg / 2;

        var config = extend$1(this._config, {
            totalAngle: totalAngle,//deg,
            percent: percentRatio,//%
            diameter: this._config.diameter * sizeRatio$1,//px
            start: startDeg,//deg
            animation: "into",
            menus: menus
        });
        
        return new CMenu(subMenu, creator._cMenu)
            .config(config);
    }

    function Creator(cMenu, config){
        this._cMenu = cMenu;
        this._container = cMenu._container;
        this._config = config;
        this._calc = new Calculation(config);
        this._anchors = [];
    }


    Creator.prototype = {
        constructor: Creator,
        createMenu: createMenu,
        _createLists: createLists,
        _createList: createList,
        _createAnchor: createAnchor,
        _createText: createText,
        _createHorizontal: createHorizontal,
        _createIcon: createIcon,
        _createSubMenu: createSubMenu
    };

    const defaultConfig = {
        totalAngle: 360,//deg,
        spaceDeg: 0,//deg
        background: "#323232",
        backgroundHover: "#515151",
        pageBackground: "transparent",
        percent: 0.32,//%
        diameter: 300,//px
        position: 'top',
        horizontal: true,
        animation: "into",
        hideAfterClick: true
    };


    function config (config) {

        config = extend$1(defaultConfig, config);

        this._creator = new Creator(this, config);
        this._creator.createMenu();

        return this;
    }

    function setCoordinate(coordinate){
        if( !(coordinate instanceof Array) || !(coordinate.length === 2) ) return;

        //TODO verify if has unit
        style(this._container, 'left', coordinate[0] + "px");
        style(this._container, 'top', coordinate[1] + "px");
    }

    //check disabled

    function setDisabled(){
        this._creator._anchors.forEach(function(v){
            v.setDisabled();
        });
    }

    function show (coordinate) {


        setDisabled.call(this);

        setCoordinate.call(this, coordinate);

        classed(this._container, 'opened-nav', true);
        return this;
    }

    function hide () {
        classed(this._container, 'opened-nav', false);
        return this;
    }

    function styles (styles) {
        if(!styles instanceof Object) return this;
        
        for(var k in styles){
            if(styles.hasOwnProperty(k)) style(this._container, k, styles[k]);
        }

        return this;
    }

    function CMenu(element, pMenu){
        this._container = element;
        
        if(pMenu) this._pMenu = pMenu;
    }

    CMenu.prototype = {
        constructor: CMenu,
        config: config,
        show: show,
        hide: hide,
        styles: styles

    };

    function index (selector) {
        return typeof selector === "string"
            ? new CMenu(document.querySelector(selector))
            : new CMenu(selector);
    }

    return index;

}));

//circular-menu

    var ele = document.querySelector('#circle-menu1');
    var cmenu = CMenu(ele)
            .config({
                        totalAngle: 40,//deg,
                        spaceDeg: 0,//deg
                        background: "#52BCEC",
                        backgroundHover: "#d3d3d3",
                        percent: 0.20,//%
                        diameter: 270,//px
                        position: 'top1',
                        horizontal: true,
      hideAfterClick: false,
                        animation: "into",
                        menus: [
       {
                                title: 'Global Finance',
                                icon: '',
                                href: '#5',
                                menus: [
                                    {
                                        title: 'DELTA - CLAN',
                                        icon: '',
          menus: [
           {
            title: 'ANS CLAN',
            icon: '',
           }
          ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                        ]
                    }).show();
```